# How to display 2 items of array in single run in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Suppose the array has ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "fbf", "fddg",.....]
The how can we display the above array like below ?

```html
    <div>
       <span>Volvo</span>
       <span>BMW</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <span>Toyota</span>
       <span>fbf</span>
    </div>
```

and so on in laravel/php?

Comment: Use the modulos operator to determine if it's an even number to create a new div with spans in a foreach loop. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#loops

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code will help you..

```
@php
$array = ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "fbf", "fddg"];
$count = 1;
@endphp

@foreach ($array ?? [] as $value )
@if($count != 2)
    <div>
        <span>{{$value}}</span>
@elseif($count == 2)
        <span>{{$value }}</span>
    </div>
    @php
        $count=0;
    @endphp
@else
    </div>
@endif
    @php
    $count++;
    @endphp
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides a `$loop` variable inside the `@foreach` loop

You can use it like this:

```
@foreach ($collection as $item)
    @if ($loop->iteration % 2)
        <div>
            <span>{{ $item }}</span>
        @else
            <span>{{ $item }}</span>
        </div>
    @endif
    
    @if ($loop->count % 2 && $loop->last)
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```